# Different ways of writing on a given element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to explore any possible coding option that I can use to simplify my code or have a better flexibility on writing the code.
If I have this element nest..

```
<table>
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
   <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

if I want to write text on first columns, I can do

```
$("table tr").each(function({
  // how to write text here on all first column using $(this)?
  // other ways to write on first column?
});
```

// other ways to write all first column not using ".each"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("table tr").each(function({
    $(this).find('td:first').text('Some text');
});
```

Comment: Not as good as adding the td:first to the original selector, but meets the OP's stated goal of using $(this) inside each.  I had this (except I used html()) written when I saw your answer pop up.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [first](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/first) selector:

```
$('table tr td:first').each(function(){
    $(this).text('1st column');
});
```

Or without using each:

```
$('table tr td:first').text('1st column');
```

---

I hope I got your comment right. If you do not want to use first for some reason, you could check whether [prev()](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/prev#expr) is empty inside your call to each().

```
if ($(this).prev().length == 0){
    // $(this) references the first column
}
```

Comment: I know it sound inefficient, but is there a way to write it using the ".each" and $(this)? I am trying to see the capabilities of jquery.

Comment: Instead of do stuff, I'd suggest .each( function() { ... } ), unless of course, you've got a *doStuff* plugin.